# data1.cab doesn't include all files when use InstallShield to compile msi

Tags: windows-installer, installshield

I'm using InstallShiled 2014 SP1 standalone to build a msi which will generate a cabinet file "Data1.cab". In past years, the msi comes out successfully, the size of data1.cab is 95KB. But in recent days, the size of data1.cab is only 25KB, lots of binaries didn't compress into cab. The build log show succeed. This lead to `error 1334, the file xxx cannot be installed beacause the file cannot be found in cabinet file "Data1.cab".`
But I didn't change anything. After I found this issue, I rebuild msi, everything back to normal.
Compare the build logs and system event viewer, no error find.
Does anyone meet this problem? Is it a InstallShiled bug?

Comment: Is this problem reproducible?  There isn't really enough forensics here to give you an answer on what happened.   Are you 100% positive that the log file references is the one for the MSI observed?

Comment: I will say that every time I saw a corrupt MSI  I saw a build log with errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I solved this problems. After I expand the disk free space from 10GB+ to 30GB, the issue disappear. I know this solution does not make sense, and could not explain why rebuild succeed. But I didn't change anything besides disk size. Hope this can help someone.

Answer (score 0):

If everything is back to normal after a new build, then it does sound like a bug. [You should contact Installshield support](https://flexeracommunity.force.com/customer/) to get more information.

Perhaps try to search for "**error 1334**" in their **Knowledge Base**: https://flexeracommunity.force.com/customer/CCKnowledgeBase. I get several articles with information.

I also get several hits when searching their online forum for "**error 1334**": https://community.flexerasoftware.com.

I hope this will help you help yourself. I don't have the time to check it all. I think shooting an email to support could give you a standard answer that would save you some time?